# do we need more than a single thread for boss group?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, netty

I mean an argument of `NioEventLoopGroup(threadsAmount)` constructor. If I understand this well, situations where we need more than one thread to accept incoming connections, are exceptionally rare.

In what kind of situations would we need more than one thread to accept incoming connections? I was thinking of maybe when the connections handlers are light and extremely short-living.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mostly if you share the NioEventLoopGroup between different ServerBoostraps.