# Netty EventLoopGroup sharing

Tags: netty

1. Does it make sense to have EventLoopGroup on client side in netty as it just have single connection with server, If no than should we use EventloopGroup(1) as we have single connection

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig for your suggestion

Comment: Btw I posted these questions together as they are related to each other

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1):

2) I've already answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34278630/1991579):

> If you are using 1 thread, for example,  in EventLoopGroup for boss
>   group for 2 different bootstraps, it means that you can't handle
>   connections to this bootstraps simultaneously. So in very very bad
>   case, when boss thread handle only connections for one bootstrap,
>   connections to another will never be handled.
>
> Same for workers EventLoopGroup.

3) You can do it, and it will work fine. But same as in 2: you can't handle server response simultaneously. If it's ok for you, do it.